# How to find the min values from indecies?

Tags: r, vector

I have a 1D matrix with column's names:

```
m<-matrix(c(1,2,3,1,1) ,1)
colnames(m)<-c("a","b","c","d","f")
```

The values can be repeated. I need to find the min values and column names.
Expected result is:

```
a d f
1 1 1
```

**My attempt is:**

```
t(apply(m,1,function(x) which(x==min(x))))

#     a d f
#[1,] 1 4 5
```

**Question**. How to find the min values from indecies?

Comment: if there is only a single row, you can directly use the `min` as `m[,m == min(m), drop = FALSE]`.  Also, your code is looping over the rows.  Not clear when there are more than one row, what will be the expected i.e. `m[,t(apply(m,1,function(x) which(x==min(x)))), drop = FALSE]`

Comment: Perhaps, this also helps i.e. `m[,colSums(m == min(m)) >0, drop = FALSE]`